# Angular ngIF is not working with my object property to apply a condition to show and hide

Tags: angular, directive

I am writing a condition with the *ngIf in my HTML code. I have a object which contains a property to show and hide a mat-list-item.

Here is the code

```
<mat-list-item  *ngIf="object.conditionName" 
 [ngClass]="((object.show) || i%2 != 0) ? 'myCssColor' : 'odd'">
```

In my ts code

```
public showDetails: boolean = false;

object: [{ name: 'MyName', conditionName: 'showDetails'}];
```

I did a test and set the *ngIf to conditionName which is showDetail but the UI is displaying the row in the mat-list-item. basically it did not work and could not read the false.

If I did this

`*ngIf="showDetails"`. This works and the UI is not showing the row.

also `*ngIf="false"` works too.

In each of my table row, there is a different ngIf condition name like `showDetail1, showDetail2`, etc...

I need to read the object and it property which are the names of my ts class booleans.

I am not sure why `*ngIf="object.conditionName "` is not work or cannot read.

Also,

if the   `*ngIf="object.conditionName "` , on my VS Code, the intellisense cannot see the object property but it can list all the properties inside the ngClass.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean object.conditionName instead of object.clauseName?

Comment: Are you sure you set the property to public in ts file?

Comment: As far as I know, this will not work because object.conditionName returns a string

Answer (score 4):

I think you're misunderstanding how `*ngIf` works in this situation. You aren't looking at the `showDetails` property on the component, you're just checking whether the string "showDetails" is truthy, which of course it is.

If you want it to point to a property on the component, you have to specifically tell it to do that, like this: `*ngIf="this[object.conditionName]"`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this to get it to work

*ngIf="this[obejct.conditionName]"

Answer (score 0):

As said in the above reply, it's not checking whether it is truthy or not, rather than that you need to provide the actual condition.

For me this worked.

<mat-list-item *ngIf="value === true">